# Adding Dynamic navigation link with PHP for Buddypress/Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation, html-lists, buddypress

I am trying to add a dropdown navigation for my buddypress/wordpress site that has a dynamic link that goes to the blog of the user that is logged in.

I want this link to appear in a subnav of a "My Profile" link that is dynamic as well (which is currently working fine).

Here is my code that I feel is almost right, but it's giving me an error saying there's "a division by zero".

```
    add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'my_nav_menu_profile_link' );
function my_nav_menu_profile_link($menu) {      
        if (!is_user_logged_in())
                return $menu;
        else
                $profilelink = '<li><a href="' . bp_loggedin_user_domain( '/' ) . '">' . __('My Profile') . '</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu"><li class="left-nav"><a href="http://www.doodlesncompany.com/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li class="left-nav"><a href="<?php echo home_url(). '/artist/' . bp_get_displayed_user_username(). '/'; ?>">Art Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
            </li>';
                $menu = $menu . $profilelink;
                return $menu;
}
```

Everything is currently working fine except for the "Art Blog" navigation.

Comment: Do you have more details as to what is causing the division by zero?  A stack trace perhaps?

Comment: Um, I guess I'm not sure.  Sorry.

I tried a couple modifications that did not give me an error.  But instead of having a dynamic link it only linked to www.doodlesncompany.com/artist/  and nothing more

Comment: Would this be the error?

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://doodlesncompany.com/artist/ from frame with URL http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-952545263902349…mpany.com/&fasl=2.200.200.2078542487..7538764325..&fu=0&ifi=1&ea=0&dtd=114. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Answer (score 0):

`bp_get_displayed_user_username()` function works only when you are in a user profile page. if you are not in profile page, that will return null
that's why you got `www.doodlesncompany.com/artist/`